# Applescript to list computers shared on network (ala "shared" finder folder)?

Tags: macos, networking, applescript, samba

Looking for a way to get a list of shared computers on a local network via applescript.

I'd like to build on this list in order to determine if a computer I know is available for sharing or not.  A bit more info: these computers show up in the "shared" part of the finder window in OsX.  So, I assume they're SMB shares as we are heavily windows based.  Is there a way to access the list of the currently available shared computers (say by name or ip) by way of Finder or other tool?

I'd love a searchable list of strings, but I can manipulate it into that if we have good output from a command most likely.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax

```
choose remote application with prompt "Select Finder on the computer of your choice..."
```

lets you choose a computer that is available on Bonjour or enter an IP address. After choosing a computer, the user can select an application, e.g. Finder. You can use the result in the "tell application" command.